# SAS simple Macro - Error

Tags: macros, sas, sas-iml

Why this very easy Macro programme :

```
%macro test1(N=,NN=);
proc iml;
start fun_test(x) global(&NN,&N);
x=&NN+&N;
finish fun_test;
call fun_test(x);
print x;
run;
quit;
%mend test1;
%test1(N=10,NN=22);
```

Gives the error? :

```
      22
ERROR 22-322: Expecting a name.
ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.
```

Comment: Actually, it gives thé right answer but this error still

Comment: Shouldn't it be more like: `%macro test1(N,NN);
proc iml;
start fun_test(x) global(&NN,&N);
x=&NN+&N;
finish fun_test;
call fun_test(x);
print x;
run;
quit;
%mend test1;
%test1(10,22);`

Comment: Thank you  @jj72uk but i still have the same error

Comment: We can also add : Options symbolgen; befor calling the macro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GLOBAL clause on the START statement expects the names of valid SAS identifiers. When you call the macro, the program resolves to

```
   start fun_test(x) global(22,11);
    ...
```

which is not valid syntax.

Maybe this is what you are looking for?

```
%macro test1(N=,NN=);
proc iml;
start fun_test(x) global(N,NN);
x=N + NN;
finish fun_test;
N = &N; NN = &NN;
call fun_test(x);
print x;
run;
quit;
%mend test1;
%test1(N=10,NN=22);
```